# set focus on area tag in angular

Tags: angular, accessibility, area

Currently i am having different rectangular images on area tag inside the map tag.

```
<map name="test" style="z-index:99999">
            <area href="javascript:void(0);"
                  [shape]="'rect'" *ngFor="let coords of imagesCoords"
                  [coords]="coords.AreaCoordinates.manipulatedCoords"
                  [target]="'_self'" 
                  [ngStyle]="{'top': coords.customTop+'px', 'left': coords.customLeft+'px', 'width': coords.customWidth+'px', 'height': coords.customHeight+'px'}"
                 
                 />
          </map>
```

Basically i want focus visually display when user access each image via keyboard/mouse.
How we can set focus on each image in area tag?

Comment: What information would a screen reader user expect to hear when they focus this item? What is the purpose of making the item interactive. We need to know this to offer the best advice but the short answer is `tabindex="0"` will give you the functionality to focus a normally not focusable item.

Comment: 1.Screen reader user expect to hear name/description of the item like for e.g 20% off on product abc.
2. Purpose of making is to make accessible for keyboard users (ADA)
hope this clear my requirements @GrahamRitchie

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, from the example given there is no accessible information, you need to use `alt`, `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby` or similar to make the `area` have some text that a screen reader can read out. I also meant what happens when the user clicks an item as you have a `javascript:void` as the `href`. `javascript:void(0)` in a `href` is often code smell that you are not doing something quite right accessibility wise as a hyperlink should always point to a URL and be part of navigation, if this is to display a popup there may be better and more semantic ways to achieve this.

Comment: Do you have a publicly accessible version of the page so we can see if there is a better way of doing what you are doing (or confirm the way you are doing it is correct and help with the focus issue). As I said though `tabindex="0"` will add the item to the focus order on the page so that answers how to set the focus. You then just need CSS focus indicator using `area:focus{outline: 2px solid #333;}` for example.